# Is this a valid use of the new keyword in my interface?

Tags: c#

In the below code, is the use of `new` valid? The objective is to allow users of `IPropertyChange` to expect the correctly typed `Origin` property. Any caution when using this pattern?

```
public interface IChangeSource { }
public interface IProperty:IChangeSource { }
public interface ISpecialProperty:IProperty { }


public interface IChange
{
    IChangeSource Origin { get; }
}

public interface IPropertyChange: IChange
{
    new IProperty Origin { get; }
}

public interface ISpecialPropertyChange:IPropertyChange
{
    new ISpecialProperty Origin { get; }
}
```